# My discord.js has an error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: discord.js

My Problem is that my bot tells me when i hit the reaction of the embed message that name is undefied. I don´t know how to fix this or how i should define **name**. I also dont know if this code, the reactionMemberAdd part works for many roles. It would be very great if one can help me

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const fs = require("fs")
const generalrolesConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./configs/generalroles.json', 'utf-8'))


module.exports = client => {

    //Allgemein
    //Chat Nachricht um Embed aufzurufen: general :space_invader: 813828905081110568 :computer: 815181805350682655 :frame_photo: 815181807234449428
    //id von member:813828905081110568 
    //id von programmierer: 815181805350682655 
    //id von grafiker/desginer: 815181807234449428 

    client.on('message', async (msg) => {
        if(msg.author.bot || !msg.guild) return;

        if(msg.content.startsWith('!general')) {
            var args = msg.content.split(' ')
            if(args.length == 7) {
                var emoji1 = args[1]
                var roleid1 = args[2]
                var emoji2 = args[3]
                var roleid2 = args[4]
                var emoji3 = args[5]
                var roleid3 = args[6]
                var role = msg.guild.roles.cache.get((roleid1 || roleid2 || roleid3))

                if(!role) {
                    msg.reply('Die Rolle gibt es nicht'); return
                }

                var generalembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Allgemein")
                    .setColor("RED")
                    .setDescription('TEST')

                var sendedMessage = await msg.channel.send(generalembed)
                    sendedMessage.react(emoji1).then(sendedMessage.react(emoji2)).then(sendedMessage.react(emoji3))

                var toSave = {message: sendedMessage.id, emoji1: emoji1, roleid1: roleid1, emoji2: emoji2, roleid2: roleid2, emoji3: emoji3, roleid3: roleid3}

                generalrolesConfig.reactions.push(toSave)

                fs.writeFileSync('./configs/generalroles.json', JSON.stringify(generalrolesConfig))

            } else {
                msg.reply('etwas ist falsch gelaufen')
            }
        }
    })

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if(reaction.message.partial) reaction.fetch()
        if(reaction.partial) reaction.fetch()
        if(user.bot || !reaction.message.guild) return

        for (let index = 0; index < generalrolesConfig.reactions.length; index++) {
            let reactionRole = generalrolesConfig.reactions[index]

            if(reaction.message.id == reactionRole.message && reaction.emoji1.name == reactionRole.emoji1 && !reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.cache.has(reactionRole.roleid)) {
                reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(reactionRole.role)
            }
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: `reaction` doesn't have an `emoji1` property. Do you mean `reaction#emoji`?

Comment: yes i'm sorry you're right